# Calculation conundrum

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, percentage

I'm a bit confused on how to implement this perhaps I'm just mathematically stupid...
I have a slider on my windows phone app that goes from 0 to 255 the sliders values are what are sent to the server over a socket, Now I'm also converting that into a percentage for a textblock but the percentage displays 0% when the sliders at 0 and 500% when the sliders at 255 which is the desired outcome or was but I've since  found out the % is not represented in the application on the other end as it starts at 10% (Which is '0' sent to the server) soooo 0 = 10 % and 255 = "500%";

but how do I make the percentage appear from 10% at 0 rather than 0%?? here is my current code...

```
private void _masterSpeedSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
  {
      double slVal = Math.Round(((Slider)sender).Value);
      //int total = 255;
      double percentage = (double) slVal * 1.96;

      _masterSpeedTxt.Text = String.Format("{0}%", Convert.ToString(Math.Ceiling(percentage)));

      string sendMI = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(((Slider)sender).Value));

      sendMI.PadLeft(3, '0');

      string fsSend = sendMI.PadLeft(3, '0');
      SocketConnect.sendtoFS(String.Format("FSOC206{0}", fsSend)); 
  }
```

I know if someone tells me I'm probably going to kick myself but maths was never my strong point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double percentage = 10 + (slVal / 255) * (500 - 10);
```

Comment: I told you I'd be annoyed! I did get a similiar value  but +10 dooooooooooooh! Thanks for your help!